# Threejs - How to correctly apply svg texture to .obj file

Tags: svg, three.js, textures, texture-mapping

I've just started playing around with threejs and first thing I'm trying to do is applying textures to models. I am able to load a PNG texture with something like:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/wood.png'),
});

object.material = material;
```

and it **fits perfectly** to the 3D model without doing anything else. I assume to have exported the .obj with the correct options (as PNG fits perfectly), so I attempted to create the same texture from an SVG instead.

```
var canvasElement = document.getElementById('svgTexture');
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  canvasElement.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  var texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(
    canvasElement,
    THREE.UVMapping,
    THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping, THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping,
    THREE.LinearFilter, THREE.LinearFilter,
  );

  material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture
  });
}

img.src = 'textures/wood.svg';
```

Unfortunately, the SVG texture gets loaded but **mapping is all messed up**. It seems Threejs is able to "use" the exported UVMaps if I do use a PNG, whereas It can't with the SVG.

NOTE: both files are the same texture, with same dimensions. Indeed, the PNG was created right from the SVG with SVG Converter (OS X).